# Junit Test case Spring boot controller returning null value in ResponseEntity

Tags: java, junit, mockito

In my project I am creating a rest endpoint which is responsible to consume grpc service response.
Now I want to write testcase for the controller class but the Junit test cases returning me null null values .

MyController.java

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private MyConsumerService consumer;

    public MyController(MyConsumerService consumer) {
        this.consumer=consumer;   
    }
     
    @GetMapping("/data")
    public ResponseEntity<Records> getData(@RequestParam("data") String data) {
        Records records = consumer.getGrpcResponse(data);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(Records, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

MyConsumerServiceImpl.java:

```java
public class MyConsumerServiceImpl implements MyConsumerService {
    @GrpcClient("user-grpc-service")
    private userGrpc.userBlockingStub stub;

    @Override
    public Records getGrpcResponse(data) {
        Records records = new Records();
        UserRequest request = UserRequest.newBuilder()
            .setUserName(data)
            .build();
        APIResponse response = stub.userRequest(request);
        records.setUserName(response.getUserName());
        return records;
   }
}
```

MyControllerTest.java:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyControllerTest {
    private MyConsumerService mockerService;
    private MyController controller;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup(){
        mockerService = mock(MyConsumerService.class);
        controller = new MyController(mockerService);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGet(){
        final var data="Hello";
        when(mockerService.getGrpcResponse(data)).thenReturn(new Records());
        final var responseEntity=controller.getData(data);
        assertEquals(responseEntity.getBody(),new Records());
    }
}
```

`responseEntity.getBody()` is returning `null`.

Normal flow is working fine but with Junit when I am mocking the client service call, it is returning `null`.

I am confused why always it is returning `null`.
Any idea where I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you have not added when then statement for service.getData(),
and below stubbing have not been called any where

when(mockerService.getGrpcResponse(data)).thenReturn(new Records());

use when then to mock service.getData() like this,

when(mockerService.getData(data)).thenReturn(new Records());

Comment: I am not getting your point.                                                                                                    
   final var responseEntity=controller.getData(data);                                                                          we have called the controller method right.

Comment: When you mocked the service, you have to use the when then statement like <when(mockerService.getData(data)).thenReturn(new Records());>. for the method which is called in the flow

Comment: I have mocked the service not the controller. when(mockerService.getGrpcResponse(data)).thenReturn(new Records()); getData() is a controller method.

Comment: Records records = consumer.getData(data);   This line of code confuses me on your controller.Then why you called service.getData()?

Comment: yes you are correct. I did some mistake there. sry for that. it could be Records records = consumer.getGrpcResponse(data);

Comment: Is that resolved your problem?

Comment: not yet still getting null vales. Actually in my serviceImpl class it is internally calling grpc service.                                                                                       
     @GrpcClient("user-grpc-service")
    private userGrpc.userBlockingStub stub; this stub is getting null value.                               As a result the controller also returning null values. But in normal scenario it is executing . Issue occur only when I am mocking the service.

Comment: Any idea where I am getting wrong.

Comment: When you mocking your MyConsumerService any method invocation of your service  class actually won't go into your method.So initialising/invoking private userGrpc.userBlockingStub stub; this class doesnt matter.Can you try when(mockerService.getGrpcResponse(anyString())).thenReturn(new Records()); ie Instead stubbing for one specific input, making generic to response for all kind of inputs

Comment: the below link help me to resolve the issue.                      
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/test/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldClientTest.java                                                                                                                                      Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

annotate this 'MyControllerTest' class with @WebMvcTest(MyController.class) and the rerun it will work, otherwise its not able to mock actual controller class.